# AngularJS watch DOM change

Tags: angularjs, dom, angularjs-directive, angular-ng-if

I have one `auto-carousel` directive which iterates through the linked element's **children**.

The children however are not yet loaded in the DOM, because their `ng-if`s expressions have not been parsed yet.

How can I make sure the parent directive knows there have been changes to it's DOM tree?

```
        <ul class="unstyled" auto-carousel>
          <li class="slide" ng-if="name">{{name}}</li>
          ...
          <li class="slide" ng-if="email">{{email}}</li>
        </ul>
```

I could use `$timeout` but that feels unreliable. I could also use `ng-show` instead of `ng-if` but that does not answer the question and not what I need.

Comment: According to angularJS docs, child directives is liked before parent directives. so ng-if is linked before parent directive. So parsing order is not your problem. Maybe your data is available asynchronously so ng-if is not parsed in link time.

Comment: @Alborz That's interesting. Do you have a link? If that is the case, I have a feeling the directive is linked before the models for the child elements are populated, I'll perform a test and get back to you. Don't forget my link!

Comment: @Alborz The link function is definitely taking place *after* the model is populated. I even used an extra `$scope.$apply()`.

Comment: I've created a sample. you will see that child link is executed before parent one .http://jsbin.com/udaTEraM/1/edit

Comment: @Alborz Thanks for taking the time to set that up. However I added a `console.log` at the `$watch` handler of `ng-if` - and it is clearly executed after the parent linker. Is there any way I can call the parent linker after the children are changed? Like, watch for DOM changes? (Watching for model changes is a problem because this directive is generic and used everywhere)

Comment: @Alborz I got it buddy, see my answer below :)

Answer (score 77, accepted):

So here's what I ended up doing:

I discovered you could pass a function to `$scope.$watch`. From there, it's pretty straightforward to return the value of the expression you want to watch for changes. It will work exactly like passing a key string for a property on the scope.

```
link: function ($scope, $el, $attrs) {
  $scope.$watch(
    function () { return $el[0].childNodes.length; },
    function (newValue, oldValue) {
      if (newValue !== oldValue) {
        // code goes here
      }
    }
  );
}
```

I am watching `childNodes`, not `children`, because the `childNodes` list holds elements *as well as* text nodes and comments. This is priceless because Angular uses comment placeholders for directives like `ng-repeat`, `ng-if`, `ng-switch` and `ng-include` which perform transclusion and alter the DOM, while `children` only holds elements.

Comment: This is nice! I had a situation where I needed to run a function every time an `input` element was added or removed inside a parent. So, `$scope.$watch(function () { return $(".parent input").length; }, ...`. This works awesomely, but I am wondering about performance..

Comment: Well with that you'll be calling at least one jQuery lookup, (in this case, a very bad one too) on every `$digest` cycle. That's quite bad in terms of performances. You could cache the node and then use jQuery's `find()` to improve on that

Comment: I did like this instead to listen for the content length on a contenteditable like this:
scope.$watch(function () { return element[0].innerHTML.length;}, function (n, o) { /*Do a operation*/ });

Comment: @SimonPertersen that's a clever one for `contenteditable`s!

Comment: It's also suggested to compare `newValue` with `oldValue` using [`angular.equals(newValue, oldValue)`](https://docs.angularjs.org/api/ng/function/angular.equals), even comparable values are plain numbers in the use case of this answer.

Answer (score 19):

If you need to watch for any changes deeper in the element's dom, MutationObserver is the way to go :

```
.directive('myDirective', function() {
    return {
        ...
        link: function(scope, element, attrs) {
            var observer = new MutationObserver(function(mutations) {
                // your code here ...
            });
            observer.observe(element[0], {
                childList: true,
                subtree: true
            });
        }
    };
});
```

Comment: That is interesting, however requires IE 11.

Answer (score 5):

I created a directive module for this [angular-dom-events](https://github.com/ilovett/angular-dom-events)

In your case you could

```
    <ul class="unstyled" auto-carousel>
      <li class="slide" ng-if="name" dom-on-create="nameCreated()">{{name}}</li>
      <li class="slide" ng-if="email" dom-on-destroy="emailDestroyed()">{{email}}</li>
    </ul>
```

Currently only supports `dom-on-create` and `dom-on-destroy`, but has better performance then the accepted answer because it will only fire once for each dom event, rather than repeatedly check the $watch callback.

Comment: Exactly what I was looking for. Thanks!

Comment: Is a nice one if you can modify your children, not if you are waiting for a third party element to appear

Answer (score 2):

Although I don't think it is with angular's recommendations, you could use ng-init which fires upon the initialization of the element:

```
<ul class="unstyled" auto-carousel>
    <li class="slide" ng-if="name" ng-init="recheck()">{{name}}</li>
    <li class="slide" ng-if="email" ng-init="recheck()">{{email}}</li>
</ul>
```

Comment: Typical .. exactly what I'm looking for, and the docs tell me not to use it .. https://docs.angularjs.org/api/ng/directive/ngInit

Comment: This is the only thing that worked for me. I needed to run some code after a form was dynamically inserted into the dom.

Answer (score 0):

You could try to compile the directive contents first inside your link function. For example:

```
angular.module('myApp').directive('autoCarousel', ['$compile', function ($compile) {

    return {
        templateUrl: 'views/auto-carousel.html',
        restrict: 'A',
        replace: true,
        link: function (scope, element, attr) {
            $compile(element.contents())(scope);

            // your code goes here
        }
    }
}]);
```