# $scope.$watch function not firing on nodelist.length change as expected

Tags: javascript, angularjs, model-view-controller, angularjs-scope

I would like to do something when a `<li>` element is hovered over. I thought that I could do it like this

```
$scope.$watch(function(){
    return  document.querySelectorAll("li:hover").length;
},
function(newVal, oldVal){
    console.log(newVal, oldVal);
});
```

based on a solution I found [here](https://stackoverflow.com/a/21361421/1252748). When the application loads, I see `0 0` in the console, which is what I'd expect. However when I hover over a `<li>` element, I expect to see `0 1`. But I don't see anything. I think that selector is good because entering

```
setInterval(function(){
   console.log( document.querySelectorAll("li:hover").length )
}, 500);
```

into the console will print `0` every half second until I hover over a `<li>` at which point, I'll see `1`. How can I change my `$scope.$watch` to watch the length of this nodelist?

Comment: can you use `ng-mouseover` https://docs.angularjs.org/api/ng/directive/ngMouseover ?

Comment: @Ronnie I was just experimenting with that actually, thanks! However, I'm still interested in why the `$watch` isn't watching..

Answer (score 2, accepted):

In my learning Experience,

**$scope.$watch** only watch the scope objects and scope providers. It does not watch the Jquery with dom manipulation. One think you do it assign the jquery object it in the scope and watch the change may you can proceed the next level.

```
$scope.liLength = document.querySelectorAll("li:hover").length;

$scope.$watch(function($scope){
    return  $scope.liLength;
},
function(newVal, oldVal){
    console.log(newVal, oldVal);
});
```