# Watch Number of Children Under Attribute Directive Element

Tags: angularjs, angularjs-directive

All,

I have an attribute directive called `scrolly`. The directive looks like this:

```
.directive('scrolly', function () {
return {
    restrict: 'A',
    scope: {
      scrollFunction: '&scrolly'
    },
    link: function (scope, element, attrs) {
        var raw = element[0];
        scope.$watch(element[0].children.length, function(){
          if(raw.clientHeight <= raw.scrollHeight){
            scope.scrollFunction();
          }
        });

        element.bind('scroll', function () {
            if (raw.scrollTop + raw.offsetHeight >= raw.scrollHeight) {
                scope.scrollFunction();
            }
        });
    }
};
```

})

The objective is to perform an infinite scroll. The scroll part works fine. The part that isn't working is the `scope.$watch` part. Basically, the objective for the watch portion is to execute the paging function until the element becomes scrollable at which point the scroll binding would take over. Although the purpose of my directive is paging, **I do not want to get hung up on that**. The root question is how to watch an attribute of an element.

Comment: Duplicate http://stackoverflow.com/questions/21332671/angularjs-watch-dom-change

Comment: you're right, this is a duplicate. My bad. I searched for a good long while, and didn't come across any that clearly addressed this question. Thanks!

Comment: I'm not being mean but it was literally the first entry when I googled "angular watch element"

Comment: I kept searching things like "angular directive watch element attributes"

Answer (score 0):

```
scope.$watch(angular.bind(element, function(){
       return element.children.length;
    }), function(oldValue, newValue) {
    if(raw.clientHeight <= raw.scrollHeight){
        scope.scrollFunction();
    }
});
```

Answer (score 0):

In a $watch you can use a function as the watch parameter to watch specific properties on things.

```
scope.$watch(function() {
  return element[0].children.length;
},
function() {
  // do your thang on change
})
```